# Can you have 20-50 GPU's in your computer?

Tags: graphics-card, desktop-computer, computer-building

I want to invest more in equipment and no longer use Cloud services, I want local access to really good hardware.

I'm looking to work on:

- machine learning
- Blender / 3D animation
- video editing

I'm not working on cryptocurrency mining.

However, I'm reading that your motherboard needs to be able to support that many GPU's in the first place, also your RAM needs to be scaled proportionally.  The only motherboard I could find on PCPartPicker had support for 4 GPU'S at most.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have 20-50 GPU's in a computer and how would it be done?  Also, is it just a server rack at that point?  Can that be kept in your home?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

There are [motherboards](https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?N=100007627%20600307108) that support up to 7 PCIe x16 slots.  However,  high end GPUs come on 2 slot PCIe cards.  The second slot is used for the fan assembly for heat dissipation.  It *might* be possible to create a custom liquid cooling setup that would allow for all 7 PCIe slots to be filled.  However, 7 is only 1/3 of your minimum.

The next problem is power.  Although it varies, lets just assume a high end GPU requires 300 watts at max power.  7 GPUs x 300 watts = 2100 watts.  The highest wattage PSU Ive seen is 1600.  You would have to have a minimum of two PSUs to handle the load of 1/3 of your minimum requirement.

Then onto heat.  One high end GPU can warm a room several degrees over ambient temperature.  I have heard that four can make a room uncomfortably hot.  Now, almost double that to seven and what do you think the room will feel like?  What about 20?  Or 50?  The ambient temperature of the room will need to be managed for the safe operation for you and the hardware.

Other factors will be noise, power cost, parts cost, and more.

All of these and more, are the reasons there are [render farms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Render_farm).  You can do cloud based, or [build your own](https://www.google.com/search?q=homemade%20render%20farm&oq=homemade%20render%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.5840j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), based on your budget.

Comment: What's the difference between this and a Bitcoin rig?

Comment: @24x7 Bitcoin miners don't use GPUs anymore, if they are serious. They use custom ASICs as the provide a better ROI.

Comment: @24x7 - Even when GPUs were used you were limited to a handful of GPUs per system